# Assembler code, wrong value at entering code, factorial

Tags: linux, assembly, x86, segmentation-fault, push

Here is my full code:

```
SYSCALL = 0X80
STDIN = 0
STDOUT = 1
SYSREAD = 3
SYSWRITE = 4
SYSEXIT = 1

.section .data

WYBOR_MAXLEN = 2
WYBOR: .space WYBOR_MAXLEN
WYBOR_LEN: .byte


.section .text
.globl _start

_start:

mov $WYBOR_MAXLEN, %edx
mov $WYBOR, %ecx
mov $STDIN, %ebx
mov $SYSREAD, %eax
int $SYSCALL

movl $0, %edi
mov WYBOR(, %edi, 1), %al

pushl %eax
call silnia
addl $4, %esp
movl %eax, %ebx
movl $1, %eax
int $0x80

#To jest rzeczywista definicja funkcji
.type silnia, @function

silnia:

pushl %ebp
movl %esp, %ebp
movl 8(%ebp), %eax
cmpl $1, %eax
je end_silnia

decl %eax
pushl %eax
call silnia
movl 8(%ebp), %ebx
imull %ebx, %eax

end_silnia:
movl %ebp, %esp
popl %ebp
ret
```

I wanted this program to run and enter value to count factorial from it. I can wrote value, but it will "segmenation fault". If i change pushl $LOl, to for ecample pushl $4 it will count normal factorial. Can I can change code to enter value from my keyboard to program?

@edit
I changed this fragment:

```
movl $0, %edi
mov WYBOR(, %edi, 1), %al

pushl %eax
```

If I enter anything on keyboard it will return me value "0" every time.

Comment: Wouldn't STDIN need to be 1 to use the keyboard? Sorry it's been a while.

Comment: Well, I can put a value from keyboard to program. Then it's segmentation fault.

Answer (score 0):

The exit condition for your factorial function is `n == 1` (where `n` is the argument). So if you call the function with a value of 0 (as you do now, since you've defined `LOL` to be 0) it will take a very long time before `n` reaches 1 (about 4 billion recursive calls).
 Your program is very likely to exhaust its allocated stack space before that happens.

Either change the exit condition to `n <= 1`, or make sure you never pass 0 to the function.

Comment: You are probably right, I am really bad at assember. I see it this way: I make a variable LOL, set it to 0. Then I enter for example "3" on keyboard, it goes to ecx, I put it into eax, and from eax i put it to LOL again to it should be 3. It's not of course.. Check please the code I changed. t return value "0" every time I enter anything.

Comment: I changed end of code as well to " cmpl $1, %eax
jle end_silnia" but still, only value it echo's me is "0"

Comment: And onr more thing I try to put easy numbers for now, like 3/4/5. The only problem is that "reading from keyboard" is probably not working, because if I give static numbers into pushl - it will work perfect.

Comment: My answer was for getting rid of the segmentation fault. Why your text input isn't working I don't know, but you should really check the result of each syscall. For example, the `read` syscall either returns the number of bytes read or an error code in `eax`.

Comment: Why can't I push for example (%ecx) without getting segmentation fail error?

Comment: Using a debugger to step through the code would be the best way to find out.